# Find All References list and export it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, export

I need to get a  list of the references to a specific class (usually inherits) and be able to manage it, I mean, export or simply copy all.

The VS Find all References is not usefull as I can not copy the list to elsewhere.

Do someone know a trick/tool for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Resharper. The best tool for .Net buddies. I am not sure about the physical file copy but you can generate a list of the referenced dll.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can copy Find All References results from VS.
Make sure Find All References window has focus, do Select All (Ctrl-A) and right click, then select Copy from context menu. You get a tab delimited list.
It works at least in VS2017 and VS2019.

Comment: I did this and pasted it directly into a google sheets doc and was pasted just like a column. Cheers!